# Select from table while masking a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'd like to export a table while masking a specific column, something like:

```
SELECT randomMask(userId), name, location FROM travel_location;
```

Requirements:

1. Masked column must be random but consistent for that query. Eg 2345 will always be randomized as abwr for that query.
2. Masked column must not be able to be decoded. abwr should not be able to be decoded into 2345 by me after running the query.
3. Every query should randomly mask the id differently, 2345 may be masked as abwr this time, but it should be something else next time.

example result:

[image]

Comment: So, you want a "random" value every time, that can't be repeated but should be consistent for every instance of that value, and can't be traced back to its original value (by anyone?).

Comment: Also, you've tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server, all of which are out of support, and 2008 is basically out of extended support too. What version are you *really* using? Tag that one, and that one only. I've removed the tags for the moment; add the relevant one back please. If you are using so an old version of SQL Server though you should be looking at upgrading (to be honest, you should have been looking into that years ago).

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand how the tags worked, fixed now. And yes, your assumption above is correct.

Comment: Given all of these requirements you will probably be best off just creating a temp table with all the distinct userid first and another column with a randomly generated string, then join on that rather than expecting a function.

Comment: What about if I'm allowed to use a mask key? Meaning it can only be decoded if I have the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `checksum()` to get a reasonable random value:

```
select checksum(userId)
```

Of course, there are collisions, but that is probably acceptable.

Alas, this will be the same each time you run the query.  To fix that, you could add a random number or use the time:

```
select checksum(userid + rand())
```

or:

```
select checksum(convert(varchar(255), userid) + convert(varchar(255), getdate())
```

Both `rand()` and `getdate()` are guaranteed to be the same on all rows for for each expression they occur in.  However, they will vary from query to query.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. 
I used the rand() and had to convert it btw. Not sure why getdate() was returning me the same value every time tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (works for SQL Server 2016 or more):

```
ALTER Table travel_location
ALTER COLUMN userId ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION='Random(1,100000)')
```

The users who were not granted to unmask like below wouldn't see the real value after this change.

```
GRANT UNMASK TO TestUser;
```

Comment: I may be recalling wrong, but wasn't Dynamic Data Masking introduced with SQL Server 2016? Although I've just removed them, the OP had tagged SQL Server 2000-2008 when this answer was made.

Comment: Does this meet all three of the requirements in the Q?